# How to use .click on nested divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ren8v32v/

What I want, is that the `.underline` div moves under the clicked `.block` div. The problem is, is when I click on one of the inner divs, JavaScript also sees the div above, so the animation is 'nullified'.

I was wondering if this situation knows a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `e.stopPropagation()` at the beginning of the event handler. This will prevent the event from bubbling up through the dom.

```
$('.block').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    ... stuff
```

Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ren8v32v/1/

Comment: Aah, look at that! I was looking for such a function for a long time now. Thanks alot!